# Unable to edit profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, error-message, profile-edit

I am getting this error message while trying to save after editing my account info (display name, email address, real name etc.):

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!

Answer (score 5):

A bug was introduced in the javascript on the /users/edit page - a fix is being rolled out now.

Sorry!

Comment: I can't edit my profile either.  I get the same error.

Comment: Is this bug back?

Comment: @AaronBertrand looks like [there is a new bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223761/updating-the-profile-throws-an-error-when-there-is-nothing-to-update) - fixing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand while there was a javascript error being generated after a blur event, it wouldn't have affected profile saving.  I [answered the other report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223788/3) I linked earlier.