# Unable to update stackover flow profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to edit profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63305/unable-to-edit-profile)

I am not able to update my profile.
I have tried using google chrome and mozilla.
EVen if i just click edit, make no changes and hot save, it shows the following - 
Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!