# Updating the profile throws an error when there is nothing to update

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

This is a silly bug, but I am reporting it anyway.

**Steps to reproduce:** Click <kbd>edit</kbd> on your profile. Then, without changing any fields, click <kbd>Update</kbd>.

**Result:**

> **Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:**
>
> - **temporary error updating your profile -- please try again!**

The error message is deceiving, I guess it is thrown because the `Update` command returned zero affected rows and the result of the update turned out false; just a guess.

Comment: No-repro for me. Must be related to one of the fields being empty.

Comment: @animuson it happens to me, once I update any field no error when update button is clicked. Tried it on IE, Chrome and FF.

Comment: No-repro for me either...

Comment: Guys, try it for the second time.. it should reproduce the second time...

Comment: @MeNoTalk Yep, doing it a second time worked. That's weird...

Comment: I got this on dba.stackexchange.com (I *was* trying to save a change to my profile), but I couldn't reproduce on the main site (where I was able to save my profile successfully).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This validation error is thrown when you try to edit your profile too quickly.  It's an old throttle, one that's also used when asking/answering questions.

Because we aren't checking to see if there are any changes (we just do an update with what's in the form - simpler that way), we aren't failing early/silently.

I'm going to say this isn't a priority to fix right now; just click "cancel" or don't click "Save Profile" so fast :)