# Unable to edit user profile: "Unusual error updating your profile"

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, error-message, profile-edit

When I try to edit my profile on any SE site, I get the following error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
> unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!

If it's relevant, this was tested in:

- Brave 1.30.87 [Chromium 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)] on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
- Microsoft Edge Version 94.0.992.38 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise Version 20H2.

Looks like it's a regression of this bug: [Unable to edit profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63305/228367)

Comment: Just to check, you're not trying this on any sites where you are suspended, right? (If you are, that might explain the bug.)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica No, I have no suspensions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An earlier refactoring went a little too far and removed a bit of tech debt that looked unused, but wasn't.

The fix should be live in production now. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for the report!

[image: Pixar - "Put That Thing Back Where It Came From or So Help Me" - Screenshot]

#### Actual footage of the bug-fixing process:

[Pixar - Put That Thing Back Where It Came From or So Help Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqaHBfBSSuc)
[The Washington University Aristocats - A Cappella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akXUgkW7Wp0&t=71s).

Comment: And some kind of regression test was added to detect similar problems(?).